# Statistical tests on non-homogeneous area

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, heterogeneity

Observing a highly non-homogeneous area, I would like to statistically observe and evaluate certain phenomena. Below is an example set of fields, segmented into 3 zones (Z1, Z2, Z3) using a clustering algorithm that takes into account the values that parameterize the field. On the right, there are the same fields represented as grids of samples. The top two fields are the ones on which certain phenomena has been present and the bottom two are the control fields.

Suppose at every point there are 5 values measured that are highly non-homogeneous throughout the field and we want to observe the impact of applying a fertilizer. In case of averaging the weighted harvest per area for every zone (Z1, Z2, and Z3) and comparing averages of top two and bottom two fields, the result is not that reliable.

Another option I am considering is not to take into account any parameter values but measure instead the value of every grid element Xij and compare the statistics of the top two fields with the bottom two. Doing this, I got the gaussian distributions for every field and I believe comparing the mean values would provide reliable insights.

Nevertheless, I am trying to find a reference dealing with similar problem (statistical tests on non-homogeneous samples).

Does anyone know if there might be any flaw in the case of 2nd approach (comparing distribution of grid samples)?

[image]

Comment: Not taking into account known covariates/parameters that systematically differ between the fields is one flaw in the second approach. Why not model the data with a regression (with either known parameters or the zones as covariates)? The model will account for these differences between the fields and a "treated with fertilizer" variable will give you the fertilizer effect.